# Tableau attribute assignment

Tags: attributes, aggregation, tableau-api

I have a simple dataset of six people

Person 1, City 1, College Yes

Person 2, City 1, College Yes

Person 3, City 2, College Yes

Person 4, City 2, College No

Person 5, City 2, College No

Person 6, City 3, College Yes

And what I want to do is end up with a new table that has the city, and a new variable that looks if everyone in that city went to college ("Yes" or "No")

City 1, AllInCollege Yes

City 2, AllInCollege No

City 3, AllInCollege Yes

This is all done in Tableau.  I'm struggling to create the calculated field that I will need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One easy approach is to use ATTR(College) -- i.e. put College on the shelf that you wish and change it from a dimension to an attribute. Then it will display "Yes" if all rows for the specified dimensions had "Yes" in the College field. Or it will display "No" if all rows had "No" in the College field. Or it will display "*" if the rows were mixed, some Yes and some No.

Or you can create a calculated field called, say everyone_went_to_college, defined as count(City) = count(if College = "Y" then 1 end)